# BizTalk 2010: calling a dll from GAC with dependencies

Tags: biztalk, gac, legacy, biztalk-2010

I have to call functions from a custom dll from BizTalk orchestrations (similar to this solution [Call a custom .NET component from BizTalk 2006](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/biztalk/CallCustomDllBiztalk2006.aspx)). The dll calls functions of a third party dll, which uses some other third party dlls (we are using to communicate with a legacy system).

The article [Global Assembly Cache Tool (Gacutil.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c(VS.71).aspx) says that my best bet would be to "include" the referenced dll into the dll I put into the GAC, but I don't know how to do this from Visual Studio (2010).

Any ideas to get this work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like putting them into the system PATH solved this problem.